# How to fix Safari mix-blend-mode: color-dodge bug?

Tags: css, safari, mix-blend-mode

I want to achieve some text that sits on top of an image and using `mix-blend-mode: color-dodge` to make the text looks better.

Here is the example:
https://codepen.io/pizza0502/pen/KepWGM

[image]

It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari, the text that is not on top of the image will become white...any solution on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your items in a container, isolate the container, and don't absolutely position your `h1`.

```css
div {
  isolation: isolate;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 10rem;
  color: #fb4b6b;
  mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello Mix Blend Mode</h1>
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works. So I will need to wrap the elements in a div and have the `isolation: isolate;` for the div