# mix-color-blend not working properly in safari

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue using the mix-color-blend in safari. I've checked out other answers here but they don't seem to work. I'm using a clippath to create a curved layer with a lower z-index than my text, and then I want the text to be above, and able to change colors according to the background. It's working in chrome already, but isolating the container in safari e changing position to static is not helping since I need either the background layer or the text to be position absolute. I'll attach screenshots of the desired outcome and the actual outcome.

CODE:

```css
.Homepage {
    height: 800px;
}

.HomepageColored {
    background-color: rgb(8,141,165);
    height: inherit;
    clip-path: ellipse(80% 60% at 0 0);
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}


.HomeText {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 90px;
    text-align: center;
}

.FirstLine {
    padding-right: 500px;
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: rgb(0,255,255);
}

.SecondLine {
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: rgb(8,141,165);
    mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
}

.ThirdLine {
    padding-left: 550px;
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: rgb(8,141,165);
}
```

```html
    <div className='Homepage' id='homepage'>
        <div className='HomepageColored'>
            <NavBar positions={props.positions}/>
        </div>
        <div className='HomeText'>
            <h1 className='FirstLine'><i>We believe</i></h1>
            <h1 className='SecondLine'><i>in</i></h1>
            <h1 className='ThirdLine'><i>Experiences</i></h1>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Note: I am using react, as you can probably tell by the elements inside my JS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Safari mix-blend-mode: color-dodge bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628725/how-to-fix-safari-mix-blend-mode-color-dodge-bug)