# Diffrent blending mode results between Safari and the other browsers

Tags: html, safari, tailwind-css, blending

I guess this issue does not have solution but yet I'd like to ask you.
I am playing with Tailwind and blending modes but I am getting different results only in Safari browser. It looks like Safari blend ok with underlying element but it does not blend with main container background.

**I am attaching code and pictures below for better understanding.**

[image]

**My HTML code mixed with tailwind**

```
<!-- main element has radial gradient, I thought it is issue, but it behave same with plain color

.ravn_main_gradient{
    background: radial-gradient(62.14% 122.16% at 49.03% 44.32%, rgba(33, 56, 63, 0.95) 0%, #1B2325 100%);

} -->

<main class="block w-full h-full bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-cover overflow-hidden relative mt-0 ravn_main_gradient">

<div class="card flex flex-col min-w-[365px]">
    <div class="_first max-w-[200px] max-h-[180px] bg-[#1F4952] overflow-hidden">
       <img class="w-full opacity-50 mix-blend-hard-light" src="{% static 'img/dc_shoe.png' %}">
    </div>
    <div class="_middle half_bg h-[calc(180px+5rem)] relative">

        <!-- number use mix blend overlay -->
        <p class="_number absolute -bottom-7 left-[calc(200px-1.8rem)] text-white text-6xl font-secondary font-bold tracking-negative mix-blend-overlay">02</p>
        
        <div class="font-secondary text-white pl-7 pt-7 pr-8">
            <!-- main title use blend exclusion -->
            <h3 class="text-2xl font-bold mb-5 mix-blend-exclusion">3D/AR Viewer of sneakers</h3>
            <p class="opacity-80 mb-1 font-light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p> 
            <p class="opacity-80 mb-1 font-light">Fusce dui leo, imperdiet in, aliquam sit amet.</p>
            <p class="opacity-80 mb-1 font-light">Aliquam in lorem sit amet leo accumsan lacinia.</p>
        </div>

        
    </div>
</div>

</main>
```

Is there any solution how to solve this issue? I can't find anything and I doubt there is any. Thank you.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628725/how-to-fix-safari-mix-blend-mode-color-dodge-bug/50629678 it's not in Tailwind but seems like a similar issue and Tailwind is just CSS at it's core. Safari has strange behavior with `mix-blend-mode` and many other things.

Comment: Thank you for advice @JHeth. I have already tried to play with isolates, before I made this question and it did not work.

Comment: So I wasn't sure what your `half_bg` class was, but I used an absolute positioned element to act as the extended image bottom part. And uh... this has identical behavior on Safari and Chrome https://play.tailwindcss.com/hGlYDaD2jT the number blends just fine with the background gradient. What version is your Safari?

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. Problem is in whole design decision. I have made my own answer about this. I did not expect that overflow with scrolling is problem for Safari. Really strange...Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Great work figuring out your own issue! Sounds like a Safari bug, I would say [report it](https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html) but I don't get the feeling that Safari respects developer feedback like the chromium team does.

Comment: @JHeth...Haha yes you are right. I doubt that too. There were times when I had problems with Firefox and Internet Explorer, nowadays It is often only Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks to @JHeth I figured where the problem is. It can be familiar for the others, but I did not know.
My design is like this `<main>` container is streched into full-width and full-height of `<body>`. So `<body>` and `<main>` does not move when scrolling. I added own scrolling `<section>` wrapper inside  with `overflow-scroll`. And this is culprit in Safari, **Safari refusing blend with background when it is inside element which overflow with scrolling**. When I change overflow to `overflow-hidden`, all blends are working.

```
<main class="block w-full h-full bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-cover overflow-hidden relative mt-0 ravn_main_gradient">

    <!-- SO here is it, I thought this section was not important, it shows that it is for Safari. When I change this to overflow-hidden, blending modes working as expected! Problem is I can't scroll now :( -->

    <section id="scroll_section" class="flex flex-col min-h-full h-full overflow-scroll pl-[184px]">   

 

    <div class="card flex flex-col min-w-[365px]">
        <div class="_first max-w-[200px] max-h-[180px] bg-[#1F4952] overflow-hidden">
           <img class="w-full opacity-50 mix-blend-hard-light" src="{% static 'img/dc_shoe.png' %}">
        </div>
        <div class="_middle half_bg h-[calc(180px+5rem)] relative">
    
            <!-- number use mix blend overlay -->
            <p class="_number absolute -bottom-7 left-[calc(200px-1.8rem)] text-white text-6xl font-secondary font-bold tracking-negative mix-blend-overlay">02</p>
            
            <div class="font-secondary text-white pl-7 pt-7 pr-8">
                <!-- main title use blend exclusion -->
                <h3 class="text-2xl font-bold mb-5 mix-blend-exclusion">3D/AR Viewer of sneakers</h3>
                <p class="opacity-80 mb-1 font-light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p> 
                <p class="opacity-80 mb-1 font-light">Fusce dui leo, imperdiet in, aliquam sit amet.</p>
                <p class="opacity-80 mb-1 font-light">Aliquam in lorem sit amet leo accumsan lacinia.</p>
            </div>
    
            
        </div>
    </div>

</section>    
</main>
```

I slightly changed the tailwind code from @JHeth where I demonstrate whole problem with scrolling. https://play.tailwindcss.com/IT7kkpsrhV