Red or White Type via CSS and mix-blend-mode
is it possible with css and mix-blend-mode to change the color between red and white while its hovering over red or white background?
I made a codepen, but mix-blend-mode: difference make the type blue and black instead of negative multiplying.


.page {
  min-height: 800px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.white {
  background: white;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.fixy {
  color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
<body class="page">
  <div class="red">
  </div>
  <div class="white">
  </div>
  <div class="red">
  </div>
  <div class="fixy">
    <p>RED TYPE
      <p>
  </div>
</body>



Codepen

body has a transparent background if none set , so red #f000 doesn't mix with anything and remains red , while mixing on white #fff  it ends up blue #0ff (give a white background to body to see it happening all the way down)

if I change body bg to white it still is blue on white and black on red bg. but I want white on red bg and red type on white bg. is that possible?

Yes, but you need to set a blue color to start with, so once mixed, it turns red or white mixing with either white and red : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KKORwWZ

Hello, if you did not get answers yet about Safari. You can probably add the tags or ask a new question if that one is partially answered. I could also put a bounty on your question, but i won't be able to see if that is working on safari Mac OSX to reward anyone :(

edit:
safari Mac OSX is now the issue, i do not own any Apple products and so unable to verify anything in Apple's environment. I'm also very curious to know how Safari handles layers here.
/edit.

To work as expected, your page requires a background set on body,if none set, then it is equal to transparent.
To have a red color from a background that is white :
bg #fff and color #0ff will turn to #f00
from a background that is red :
bg #f00 and color  #0ff will turn #fff
snippet:


.page {
  min-height: 800px;
  background: white
}

.red {
  background: red;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.white {
  background: white;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.fixy {
  color: #0ff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  isolation: isolate;
}
<body class="page">
  <div class="red">
  </div>
  <div class="white">
  </div>
  <div class="red">
  </div>
  <div class="fixy">
    <p>RED TYPE
      </p>
  </div>
</body>



.fixy is set to a blue color (not white nor red) that will be mixed with the background-color.
if background turns to be transparent, blue will remain blue, having nothing to mix with.
For safari's trouble, it seems that isolation:isolate; can fix the way layers are drawn :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation


I set a body bg already and its not working.
in your snippet the text is blue while its hovering red. that's what I need that it turns to red type on white bg and on white type on red bg.

@SilverStar069 ?? which browser are you using ? FF,Chrome, Edge, samsung browsers show me red or white , no blue in the snippet

damn... is that a os thingy? I use safari on a Mac... can you show me a screenshot please?

here from FF https://i.sstatic.net/i51Gmzj8.png ;)

On my Mac, this only works in Firefox ... it doesn't work in Chrome nor Safari.

@G-Cyrillus, Why didn't you close your <p> properly? Browsers are forgiving nowadays, but why to try the luck?

@Kosh I only updated CSS's op actually without paying attention to HTML . fixed within my answer. Does it make a difference for safari ?

@G-Cyrillus, on mac, both Safari and Chrome show red on white, and light blue-ish on red.

on Mac Safari its still blue and dark red. is there a fix for this? https://ibb.co/4TcBfGC

You may try to add position:relative to other container and set a z-index for all of them, it should help Safari to see where the layers are standing . transform can also help. without this OS n browser i cannot debug myself about how safari manage the layers at screen

@SilverStar069  take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628725/how-to-fix-safari-mix-blend-mode-color-dodge-bug

@SilverStar069 it seems that isolation:isolate; is fine enough to fix safari's behavior :  https://i.sstatic.net/orf7zKA4.png I updated the snippet, can you confirm ?

nothing changed with this isolation thing. Your snippet is still blue on red on safari Mac OSX

arf , so we cannot trust these online tester . Sorry, i can not help further :)

thank you very much for your help anyways. maybe someone else know an answer.
