Synchronised slide transition of foreground (text) colour and background colour
I have a setup similar to the following:


.text-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #FBFBFD;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.blended-text {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.text-container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #21B250;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}

.text-container:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="text-container">
  <span class="blended-text">Dynamic Text</span>
</div>



As you can see I'm trying to get the text change its color as the background changes.
I was trying to use some of the mix-blend-modes that exist, but I did not achieve to get the text become white on the green background but remaining black on the lightgray background.
Is it possible to achieve such with mix-blend-mode? I do want that exact behaviour of mix-blend-mode where only a part of the text has changed it's color during transition.
I guess it is not possible to define a custom mix-blend-mode, right?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79140892/red-or-white-type-via-css-and-mix-blend-mode

@Paulie_D This is another usecase and does not answer this question. In the question mentioned the text's color changes between the color of the different backgrounds. But in this case, the background is never black for example.

Instead of impossible mix-blend-mode: difference, I'd use a very different approach using background-clip: text with linear-gradient backgrounds:


.text-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #21B250 300px, #FBFBFD 300px) no-repeat -300px 0 / 600px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  transition: 1s;
}

.blended-text {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, white 300px, black 300px) no-repeat -300px 0 / 600px;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text; /* if you'd need it */
  transition: 1s;
}

.text-container:hover,
.text-container:hover .blended-text {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
<div class="text-container">
  <span class="blended-text">Dynamic Text</span>
</div>




Thank you for the answer! This seems to work perfectly fine for the example I've provided in the question. As I've simplified the code snippet in this case, my case is slightly more complex. Instead of the background (green) being just a color, I use an SVG (due to the complex form it has) where the "right" property is animated for the transition. Maybe you have an idea on how to solve it then?

@MischaBinder in this excellent solution there are two synchronised backgrounds. The background of .text-container manages the grey-green transition of the rendered background; the background of .blended-text manages the black-white transition of the rendered text. You should be able to do anything you like with the background of .text-container, as long as you keep the transition duration (and timing function) the same as .blended-text.

@MischaBinder, you might put your SVG or any other image as a background of the container. Actually, you probably shouldn't have your question simplified, so you'd get more suitable answer. I maybe have an idea though =))
